# StencilJS + Facebook Instant Game, app-root not rendering

Tags: javascript, facebook, configuration, stenciljs, facebook-instant-games

I am trying to set up my facebook instant game.

I have followed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/test-publish-share , to test locally then deploy into production.

When testing, everything works fine. However, in production, nothing shows up (black screen) when I open my game. `<app-root>` doesn't render, app-home's constructor isn't called and it takes up 0x0 pixels.

This is my index.html

```
<!--
  Copyright (c) 2017-present, Facebook, Inc.
  All rights reserved.
  This source code is licensed under the license found in the
  LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="full-screen" content="yes" />
  <meta name="screen-orientation" content="portrait" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />

  <script type="module" src="/build/app.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="/build/app.js"></script>
  <link href="/build/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/assets/icon/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.6.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    const assets = [
      'img/asset1.png',
      'img/asset2.png',
      'img/asset3.png',
      'img/asset4.png'
    ];

    window.onload = function () {

      // When the window loads, start to initialize the SDK
      FBInstant.initializeAsync().then(function () {

        // We can start to load assets
        for (let i in assets) {
          // When preloading assets, make sure to report the progress
          FBInstant.setLoadingProgress(i / assets.length * 100);
        }

        // Now that assets are loaded, call startGameAsync
        FBInstant.startGameAsync().then(() => console.log("initialized"));
      });
    };
  </script>

  <app-root></app-root>

</body>

</html>
```

'initialized' is printed in the console, when I open the game. There are two errors there with it (which might have to do with the error I am having)
[Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUMpy.png)

The 404 error (resource not found) is a .js file which I checked was included in the .zip file which I uploaded.

This is what i see when I inspect element on the game
[Inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm6dA.png)

Also, on mobile, nothing is displayed (white screen)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks! :)

Comment: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT here most likely means, the JS resource got blocked by some sort of ad blocker or privacy extension …

Comment: I have disabled adblocker and tried again. The ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT message has disappeared, but the net::ERR_ABORTED 404 remained. Would you know how I could fix this? Thanks